# How can I divide two Eigen::Vector3f by the corresponding elements

Tags: c++, eigen

I need to divide two vectors by the corresponding elements. How can I accomplish this? I couldn't find any good sources. Something like

```
Eigen::Vector3f v1 = { 10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f };
Eigen::Vector3f v2 = { 5.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f };
Eigen::Vector3f v3 = v1 / v2;
```

Expected result:

```
{ 2.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f }
```

It says "no operator `/` matches the operands" for division.

Comment: You can remap then onto an `Array` and use elementwise operations on that. See [Converting between array and matrix expressions](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the builtin matrix (expression) types support common linear algebra operations through overloaded operators (e.g. matrix-vector multiplication), Eigen provides distinct types for component-wise operations; the are called "arrays" and subsume `Eigen::Array<...>` instantiations as well as array expressions. You can always wrap a matrix into an array expression and vice-versa by the `.array()` and `.matrix()` member functions - they don't copy anything, but repackage the underlying data such that array-associated operations can be used for matrices, or matrix-associated operations for arrays. In your case, this would be

```
const Eigen::Vector3f v1 = { 10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f };
const Eigen::Vector3f v2 = { 5.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f };
const Eigen::Vector3f v3 = v1.array() / v2.array();
```

If you don't need the matrix interface at all, you can also use `Eigen::Array<...>` directly:

```
const Eigen::Array3f a1 = { 10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f };
const Eigen::Array3f a2 = { 5.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f };
const Eigen::Array3f a3 = a1 / a2;
```